# How do I deal with a data race in OpenMP?

Tags: c, for-loop, openmp

I am trying to use OpenMP to add the numbers in an array. The following is my code:

```
  int* input = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*snum);
  int sum = 0;
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<snum;i++){
      input[i] = i+1;
  }
  #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
  for(i=0;i<snum;i++)
  {
      int* tmpsum = input+i;
 sum += *tmpsum;
  }
```

This does not produce the right result for `sum`. What's wrong?

Comment: `sum` should be a *reduction* variable, `reduction(+:sum)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your code currently has a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), which is why the result is incorrect. To illustrate why this is, let's use a simple example:

You are running on 2 threads and the array is `int input[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};`. You initialize `sum` to `0` correctly and are ready to start the loop. In the first iteration of your loop, thread 0 and thread 1 read `sum` from memory as `0`, and then add their respective element to `sum`, and write it back to memory. However, this means that thread 0 is trying to write `sum = 1` to memory (the first element is `1`, and `sum = 0 + 1 = 1`), while thread 1 is trying to write `sum = 2` to memory (the second element is `2`, and `sum = 0 + 2 = 2`). The end result of this code depends on which one of the threads finishes last, and therefore writes to memory last, which is a race condition. Not only that, but in this particular case, neither of the answers that the code could produce are correct! There are several ways to get around this; I'll detail three basic ones below:

**`#pragma omp critical`**:

In OpenMP, there is what is called a `critical` directive. This restricts the code so that only one thread can do something at a time. For example, your `for`-loop can be written:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
for(i = 0; i < snum; i++) {
    int *tmpsum = input + i;
#pragma omp critical
    sum += *tmpsum;
}
```

This eliminates the race condition as only one thread accesses and writes to `sum` at a time. However, the `critical` directive is very very bad for performance, and will likely kill a large portion (if not all) of the gains you get from using OpenMP in the first place.

**`#pragma omp atomic`**:

The `atomic` directive is very similar to the `critical` directive. The major difference is that, while the `critical` directive applies to anything that you would like to do one thread at a time, the `atomic` directive only applies to memory read/write operations. As all we are doing in this code example is reading and writing to sum, this directive will work perfectly:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
for(i = 0; i < snum; i++) {
    int *tmpsum = input + i;
#pragma omp atomic
    sum += *tmpsum;
}
```

The performance of `atomic` is generally significantly better than that of `critical`. However, it is still not the best option in your particular case.

**`reduction`**:

The method you should use, and the method that has already been suggested by others, is `reduction`. You can do this by changing the `for`-loop to:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) reduction(+:sum)
for(i = 0; i < snum; i++) {
    int *tmpsum = input + i;
    sum += *tmpsum;
}
```

The `reduction` command tells OpenMP that, while the loop is running, you want each thread to keep track of its own `sum` variable, and add them all up at the end of the loop. This is the most efficient method as your entire loop now runs in parallel, with the only overhead being right at the end of the loop, when the `sum` values of each of the threads need to be added up.

Comment: There are quite some places in your answer where you've used _process_ while the correct word would be _threads_. You might want to correct this to prevent confusion.

Comment: @HristoIliev: Righto. I'm writing an MPI code at the moment, so I've been thinking in terms of processes all day; hence the mixup. Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: thanks for you answer,and if the var-sum is a array,like this "int sum[2]".I used #pragma omp reduction(+:sum) and #pragma omp reduction(+:sum[0]) #pragma omp reduction(+:sum[1]),doesn't work! what can I do?

Comment: @YOung: Don't make `sum` an array; in fact, keep the code before the loop exactly the same as it was before. NikolayKondratyev provides a working code sample in the other answer. To clarify: while I did say that each thread will keep track of its own `sum` variable, the compiler will take care of that for you with the `reduction` directive; you do not need to set up an array yourself. In fact, setting up an array yourself will confuse the compiler, and cause the code to produce incorrect results, as you've seen.

Comment: @wolfPack88 using "reduction" ,I got the right answer.but I try to use "critical" or "automic" to do this.I found the "reductioin" solution is almost twice as fast as others;How can I use phtread or openmp to get this performance

Comment: @YOung: I'm not sure what you mean; the `reduction` directive **is** an OpenMP directive. You are getting this performance by using OpenMP.

Comment: @wolfPack88 I means that I want to know why the reduction directive can do such a good performance and what is the implementation of the reduction ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `reduction` clause ([description at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/88b1k8y5.aspx)).

```
int* input = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*snum);
int sum = 0;
int i;
for(i=0;i<snum;i++){
    input[i] = i+1;
}
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) reduction(+:sum)
for(i=0;i<snum;i++)
{
    sum += input[i];
}
```