# OpenMP shared variable behaves like private

Tags: c, openmp

```
#pragma omp  parallel  shared(c,z)
{
    #pragma omp for private(i,j)
    for(i=0;i<righe;i++)
    {
        printf("Z=%d\n",z);
        for(j=0;j<colonne;j++)
            printf("");
        z++;
    }
}
```

Output is Z=0 or Z=1 when it should be 1,2,3..

Comment: Please declare loop variables in the loop header. Then you don't have to worry about private/shared.

Comment: Note that your inner (`j`) loop doesn't actually do anything and will likely be optimized away. (A good compiler will recognize that printing a null string is a NOP.) But you need to show more code - a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: the code is simplified for easier understanding. I put a print of the value of j now
The problem is that z is not modified or is not always modified while at each iteration of i it should increase it

Comment: #pragma omp  parallel  shared(c,z)
 {
  
  
  #pragma omp for 
  for(i=0;i<righe;i++)
  {
   printf("Z=%d\n",z);
   for(j=0;j<colonne;j++)
   printf("J=%d\n",j);
  
  z++;
  }
 }

Comment: There is a race condition on `z`, so the final value is unpredictable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I deal with a data race in OpenMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998183/how-do-i-deal-with-a-data-race-in-openmp)